# How to hide NavigationBar when the view disappears in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

```
struct SomeView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      //rest of the code goes here
    }.navigationBarTitle("Some View")
  }
}
```

I am trying to hide my view's NavigationBar using .onDisappear{} but it doesn't work and throws a warning. How can I hide my NavigationBar when the view disappears or some condition returns true but not otherwise?

Comment: show us the code you are using, it's easier to understand the question then

Comment: i have edited the question with a sample code. i just want to hide the navigation bar when I switch from this view to another view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide navigation bar view - navigationBarHidden option

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State private var condition = false
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Toggle(isOn: $condition) {
            Text("Hide NavigationBar View")
        }.padding(.horizontal)
       .navigationBarTitle("Some View")
        .navigationBarHidden(condition)
    }
  }
}
```